# Node.js -TypeError : Object 1800000 has no method 'toUTCString'

Tags: node.js, session, express, cookies

I am using session management in my Node.js Application.with default express-session available for Express MVC application.
in **app.js** file i am including my cookie and session expire time.

```
app.use(session({
secret: 'ssshhhhh',
saveUninitialized: true,
resave: true,  
cookie:{maxAge:new Date(Date.now() + 1800000),expires:1800000},rolling:true})
);
```

But when i execute the my code it throws ans Error Called **TypeError: Object 1800000 has no method 'toUTCString'**
Please provide any working solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`maxAge` should be a relative amount (*X milliseconds from now*), whereas `expires` should be an absolute timestamp (*at this date and time*). You're doing the exact opposite for both.

In other words, try this:

```
cookie : {
  maxAge  : 1800000,
  expires : new Date(Date.now() + 1800000),
  rolling : true
}
```

(although I'm not sure if `expires` is even a valid option for `express-session`)

Comment: I tried this but after doing this the session expires time goes to - negative.

Comment: and basically this is happening when website is on server.

Comment: @arjunkori are you sure the system times of both server and client are up-to-date?